# I want to create, write, open, read, and close my file. For some reason it is not doing anything

Tags: assembly

This is my code for creating, writing, reading, and closing file but as soon as I run the program it closes and nothing has been created. What am I doing wrong?

```
.model tiny
.data

file   db "file.txt",0
buffer db 256 dup(?)    ;data buffer    

.code
.stack

cseg segment 'code'

assume cs:cseg, ds:cseg

org 100h

;creating a file

mov ah, 3Ch
xor cx, cx
mov dx, offset file
int 21h
jc error

;write file

mov bx, ax
mov ah, 40h
mov cx, 256
mov dx, offset buffer
int 21h
jc error

;open file

mov ah, 3Dh
mov al, 0
mov dx, offset file
int 21h
jc error

;read file

mov bx, ax
mov ah, 3Fh
mov cx, 256
mov dx, offset buffer
int 21h
jc error

;closing file

mov ah, 3Eh
int 21h

error:
mov ax, 4C00h
int 21h

cseg ends

end
```

Comment: have you tried running it through a debugger?

Comment: I directly ran it through tasm. I am using this concept to slowly approach to my Huffman compression and decompression project

Answer (score 1):

Since your program is created as a .COM (see the ORG 256) you need to jump over the data at the beginning. But it's better to put the DATA below the CODE.

You should first close the file before you re-open it to read from it!